# How can I make a condition to add reference when I have many Project references and dll references

Tags: msbuild

Here is my code, I have added ProjectReference test1,test2,test3,test4, but some of them may not exist, so I need to add dll reference to test1.dll, test2.dll...and I have many dlls, not just 4 test files.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="test1.csproj" /> 
        <ProjectReference Include="test2.csproj" /> 
        <ProjectReference Include="test3.csproj" /> 
        <ProjectReference Include="test4.csproj" /> 
        <Reference Include="test1.dll" />
        <Reference Include="test2.dll" />
        <Reference Include="test3.dll" />
        <Reference Include="test4.dll" />
        <Reference Include="test5.dll" />
    </ItemGroup>
     <Target Name="test"> 
         <Message Text="The reference name: %(Reference.filename)" Importance="high" /> 
     </Target> 
</Project>
```

The problem is, can I add dll reference on condition that it include *.csproj but there is no such csproj file? For example, one ProjectReference include test1.csproj, but no such test1.csproj file, then add a reference include test1.dll

I have tried in target, but it's not I want, the solution explorer always show project reference

Comment: Generally, you have a directory containing a solution file. The solution lists all the projects. All the projects are in sub-directories of the solution directory. A project listed in the solution may have a `ProjectReference` to another project listed in the same solution. Can you explain how you have diverged from this pattern and why a project would not exist?

Comment: For some team works, part of people have all accesses while some others do not have, so we need to precompile some dlls to use. But all of us use the same solution, so I wander if I can make a file to switch reference automatically. Do you have some advice about it?

Comment: Ouch. Those are tough working conditions. The code should be re-organized. The projects with more restricted access should be in their own solution with their own build that produces a package shared on an internal NuGet feed so that the 'all access' projects can use `PackageReference`. But I'm guessing you know that and you are trying to work around politics.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are constraints and requirements that can't be changed and you have no choice but to work with the current situation, then the following may help.

A `Condition` attribute is supported on [`Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/item-element-msbuild?view=vs-2022) elements. You could define properties that can be used as Boolean flags to flip between including the project to the `ProjectReference` item set or including the assembly to the `Reference` item set.

```xml
    <PropertyGroup>
        <!-- Default to true -->
        <IsTest1ProjectAvailable Condition="'$(IsTest1ProjectAvailable)' == ''">true</IsTest1ProjectAvailable>
        <!-- Normalize a non-true value to false -->
        <IsTest1ProjectAvailable Condition="'$(IsTest1ProjectAvailable)' != 'true'">false</IsTest1ProjectAvailable>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="test1.csproj" Condition="$(IsTest1ProjectAvailable)"/>
        <Reference Include="test1.dll" Condition="!$(IsTest1ProjectAvailable)"/>
    </ItemGroup>
```

How to know if the project is available and should be used or if the assembly is available and should be used will depend a lot on the specifics of the situation.

Instead of maintaining copies across multiple projects, create a [`Directory.Build.targets` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-by-directory?view=vs-2022) to share across all the projects.

The `$(MSBuildProjectFile)` property can be checked to prevent a project from referencing itself.

Example:

```xml
    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(MSBuildProjectFile)' != 'test1.csproj'">
        <ProjectReference Include="test1.csproj" Condition="$(IsTest1ProjectAvailable)"/>
        <Reference Include="test1.dll" Condition="!$(IsTest1ProjectAvailable)"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(MSBuildProjectFile)' != 'test2.csproj'">
        <ProjectReference Include="test2.csproj" Condition="$(IsTest2ProjectAvailable)"/>
        <Reference Include="test2.dll" Condition="!$(IsTest2ProjectAvailable)"/>
    </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Great! that's what I'm using now.